# How to distinguish between 2 free products on the same number of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I am currently learning algebraic topology (using Munkres/Hatcher)

So far I've seen that the fundamental group of the "figure 8 space" is $\langle a, b \rangle$ or simply the free product on 2 generators.

Then, we can also calculate the fundamental group of the Klein bottle which was $\langle a, b : aba = b \rangle$ (an application of Van-Kampen's theorem).

I was wondering if this is enough information to distinguish the two spaces. Can I claim that these 2 free products are non-isomorphic? (the presentation with no relations seems to be different to one with relations). I know generators must be mapped to generators by an isomorphism but there may be different generating letters if I'm not mistaken (rather than just $a, b$, they could be a combination of them).

Do we have enough information from the fundamental groups to distinguish these spaces?

Comment: Are you familiar with the abelianization of a group? Often that can make it clear that two groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: Let me suggest getting some terminology straight regarding [free products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product). A presentation with no relators is, almost by definition, a free product, namely it is the free product of infinite cyclic groups, one such group per generator. So yes, $\langle a,b \rangle$ may be regarded as a free product. But the presentation $\langle a,b \mid aba = b\rangle$ does not define a free product *at all*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the Abelianization of both groups: the figure eight gives $\mathbb Z^2$ while for the Klein bottle you get $a^2=1$ so the group has torsion.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G_1 := \langle a,b \rangle$ and $G_2 :=\langle a,b : aba=b \rangle$. If $G_1 \cong G_2$, then for every abelian group $A$ also $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1,A) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(G_2,A)$ as abelian groups*. But the universal property of the free group modulo relations implies that $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1,A) \cong A^2$, whereas $\mathrm{Hom}(G_2,A)$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of those $(x,y) \in A^2$ such that $x+y+x=y$ in $A$, i.e. $2x=0$ and $y$ is arbitrary. If $2 : A \to A$ is injective, we get $\mathrm{Hom}(G_2,A) \cong A$. So it suffices to find a single abelian group $A$ such that $2 : A \to A$ is injective and $A \not\cong A^2$. Well, any non-trivial finite abelian group of odd order is an example. But also $\mathbb{Z}$ is an example.

This proof is, of course, essentially equivalent to the one using [abelianizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization). But the thing is: you don't have to find or use the *universal* abelian *quotient*. The homomorphisms into concrete abelian groups are sufficient.

*Conceptually, this is because $\mathrm{Hom}(-,A) : \mathbf{Grp}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ is a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor).

Comment: @downvoting person: what should I improve or change?